# Spring JPA query involving COUNT() and LOWER()

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm very new to Spring JPA/JPQL but trying to replicate the following MySQL query, without much success. We're not able to get past what looks like a syntax error which looks to be a function of trying to compound the use of COUNT() and LOWER().

The MySQL(which works) is:

```
select lower(sdetail_cvalue) as stringValue, 
count(lower(sdetail_cvalue)) as stringValueCount 
from <someTable>
where sdetail_cfield not like <someValue>
and sdetail_cfield not like <someOtherValue>
and sdetail_cfield not like <someOtherOtherValue>
group by stringValue
order by stringValueCount desc
```

and the corresponding JPQL I'm trying is

```
SELECT new <searchResult> 
(lower(sd.searchText) as searchText, 
COUNT(lower(sd.searchText)) as searchTextOccurrenceCount) 
FROM <someTable> sd 
WHERE sd.searchType not like <someValue> 
AND sd.searchType not like <someOtherValue> 
AND sd.searchType not like <someOtherOtherValue> 
GROUP BY searchText 
ORDER BY searchTextOccurrenceCount DESC
```

but get the following error message on execution

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 128 [SELECT new <REDACTED> (lower(sd.searchText) as searchText, COUNT(lower(sd.searchText)) as searchTextOccurrenceCount) FROM <someTable> sd WHERE sd.searchType not like <someValue> AND sd.searchType not like <someOtherValue> AND sd.searchType not like <someOtherOtherValue> GROUP BY searchText ORDER BY searchTextOccurrenceCount DESC]
```

I've redacted some of the above, but the column number(i.e. 128) refers to the '(' between 'lower' and 'sd.'

We've tried various ways to deconstruct the query to pinpoint the issue, which seems to that we're using a compound COUNT(LOWER()) construct. Does anyone have an example of successfully implementing such a thing using JPQL?...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about adding `nativeQuery = true` to your `@Query` annotation?